# How do I set the directory owner depending on hostname when using ansible playbook to create similar directory's across many different servers?

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-template, rhel8

I would like to create an Ansible playbook that makes a new directory on many servers. I understand how to set the mode, the group will be the same across all environments, but the owner needs to be set depending on the hostname. For example, if the hostname of a particular server is **hostnameABCdb**, the owner needs to be **ABCadm**. However, if the hostname of a server is **hostnameDEFdb**, the owner needs to be **DEFadm**. I am a jr. engineer, so fairly new to Linux/Ansible and still learning the ropes (using RHEL 8). Thanks for any feedback!

I used a two step process, but it was tedious and I know there should be another solution.
Step one- set up yml to create the directory.
Step two- set up a second yml for each server group to change the owner.

STEP 1 yml:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

  - name: Create directory /usr/dir/newdir
    file:
      path: /usr/dir/newdir
      state: directory
      recurse: yes
      owner: root
      group: chosengroup
      mode: 0755
```

STEP 2 yml:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

  - name: Change owner
    command: chown ABCadm:chosengroup /usr/dir/newdir
```

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"For server **hostnameABCdb**, the owner needs to be **ABCadm** ... for server **hostnameDEFdb**, the owner needs to be **DEFadm**"*.

A: Use Ansible special variable [inventory_hostname](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-inventory_hostname):

> *"The inventory name for the ‘current’ host being iterated over in the play"*

For example,

```yaml
- name: Create directory /usr/dir/newdir
  file:
    path: /usr/dir/newdir
    state: directory
    recurse: yes
    owner: "{{ inventory_hostname[8:] }}"
    group: chosengroup
    mode: 0755
```

Comment: Correct, more specificly `owner: "{{ inventory_hostname[8:11] }}adm"`. ... just for reference [How slicing in Python works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/).